# Diophantine equation $3^a+1=3^b+5^c$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, elementary-proofs

This is not a research problem, but challenging enough that I've decided to post it in here:

> Determine all triples $(a,b,c)$ of non-negative integers, satisfying
>   $$
> 1+3^a = 3^b+5^c.
> $$

Comment: Papers are still published on such questions (**Lucia** gave two examples, and there are others), so it's research-level (and thus fair game for Mathoverflow) even if it did not arise in your own research.

Comment: But if it's a puzzle to which OP already knows the answer, then I'd say it's not appropriate for MO.

Comment: NoamD.Elkies: thanks for your comment.
GerryMyerson: thanks. Had I known that these type of Diophantine equations are still an active area of research, would have likely phrased the problem that way. Still trying to digest the concept --- as there is a section (tag) with elementary proofs, that are contest problems, as opposed to research problems, but challenging enough that people still post.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I can't resist this:  The young [Chris Skinner](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X90901125) showed that if $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are fixed positive integers, and $p$ and $q$ are positive coprime integers then the equation 
$$
ap^x + bq^y = c+ dp^z q^w 
$$ 
has a bounded number of solutions in $(x,y,z,w)$ and that a bound on these could be computed (and the equation solved in practice).   This solves (in principle) the more general equation $1+3^a 5^d = 3^b+ 5^c$.  Anyway, there is a large literature around such exponential diophantine equations, and Skinner's paper will give some references.

Following a reference from Skinner's paper, Theorem 4.01 of [Brenner and Foster](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102724775) gives an explicit treatment of the equation 
$$ 
3^a + 7^b=3^c+5^d,
$$ 
which completely resolves the problem in this question (take $b=0$).  Their proof is elementary, and the only non-trivial solution to the equation in the question is $3^3+1 = 3 + 5^2$.

Comment: Lucia, many thanks for the paper.

Comment: I think you've missed a=n, b=n, c=0, for all $n\geq 0$ as the question asks for non-negative rather than positive integer solutions.